# Recepients are in BCC field when sending email

Tags: python-2.7, smtplib

Whenever I run my code the recipients are in the bcc field rather than the **To** field (When I check my gmail inbox)

I have no idea what can be the reason.
How can I stop the recipients being in the BCC field. and make them appear in the TO field
Here is my code

```
import smtplib 
import getpass
import time
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

smtpVar = smtplib.SMTP ("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
fromEmail = "myemail@gmail.com"
toEmails = ["myemail@gmail.com", "secondemail@gmail.com"]

msgVar = MIMEMultipart()
msgVar ["From"] = fromEmail
msgVar ["To"] = toEmails

# I am getting the contents of the body of the email from a text file
fileOpen1 = open ("EmailBody.txt", "r")
msgBody = MIMEText (fileOpen1.read())
fileOpen1.close()

smtpVar.ehlo()
smtpVar.starttls()

passwordVar = getpass.getpass (prompt="Enter Password  : ")
smtpVar.login ("myemail@gmail.com", passwordVar)

smtpVar.sendmail (msgVar ["From"], msgVar ["To"] , "Subject: Test Email-.......[Email Date/Time] " + time.strftime("%Y" + "-" + "%m" + "-" + "%d" + "_" + "%H" + ":" + "%M" + ":" + "%S") + "\n" + msgBody.as_string())

smtpVar.quit()
print ("\n\n.....message sent successfully!!!\n\n")
```

Comment: I am genuinely curious, why write `"%Y" + "-" + "%m" + "-" + "%d" + "_" + "%H" + ":" + "%M" + ":" + "%S"` instead of `"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S"`? Seems lie a lot of extra work without any benefit of clarity.

Comment: Looks like you are losing the "headers" (`From` and `To`) [18.1.11. email: Examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#email-examples)

Comment: @SethMMorton Thanks for pointing that out..Didnt know you could do that in the way you showed..Thanks will change code!

crashmstr Amazingly enough that link isnt very comprehensive for a beginner like myself I am afraid. I can understand just bit and pieces of it. Anyway Barmar explained it really well below.. Thanks for your help as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`smtplib` doesn't create the message headers for you. The `from` and `to` arguments are just used for the envelope. If you want them to appear in the header, you have to do that yourself.

```
smtpVar.sendmail (msgVar ["From"], msgVar ["To"] , "From: " + msgVar["From"] + "\nTo: " + msgVar["To"].join(", ") + "\nSubject: Test Email-.......[Email Date/Time] " + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S") + "\n" + msgBody.as_string())
```

Comment: Hi @barmar THANKS for your help!...your script had the **bold**.split**bold** in the wrong place I am afraid but I fixed it anyway. Here it is `code` smtpVar.sendmail (msgVar ["From"], msgVar ["To"].split(",") , "From: " + msgVar["From"] + "\nTo: " + msgVar["To"] + "\nSubject: Test Email-.......[Email Date/Time] " +
time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S") +
"\n\n" + msgBody.as_string())`code`
Anyway my other problem now is that in the message body some additional text has come up. how can I get rid of this?.. This is the additional text=Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version:

Comment: There's no need for `split`, `msgVar["To"]` is a list, not a string.

Comment: The extra text is because of the extra newline I added. I thought `msgBody` was just the body, I didn't know it included header lines.

Comment: **bold**THANKS VERY MUCH**bold** again @Barmar.. yeh I removed all instances of `code`split`code` and removed 1 of the \n. Everything works well now! Just out of curiosity, where can I learn these things online for myself so that I dont have to post here and bother other people for help with my code? ..**bold**thanks again!**bold**

Comment: You're welcome. Why do you write the word **bold** instead of putting the bold markup around the words?

Comment: Ha ha sorry I am a bit new hear..I misread the instructions. I thought you had to put the ** bold ** <words> ** bold ** instead of putting it like **this**..thanks for helping out on that too...really appreciate it!